# Bad Request ERROR on Fetch API call - Next 13.3,

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, openai-api

I'm currently working on a chatgpt chatbot using Next13 project following a tutorial and I'm getting a bad request error when I submit the request:

app/askai/route.ts

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import {Configuration, OpenAIApi} from "openai"

type ResponseData = {
    text: string;
}

interface GenerateNextApiRequest extends NextApiRequest{
    body:{
        prompt: string
    };
}

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export async function POST(
    req: GenerateNextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
){
    const prompt = req.body.prompt;

    if(!prompt || prompt == ''){
        return new Response('something is wrong', {status:400});
    }

    const aiResult = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: 'text-davinci-003',
        prompt: `${prompt}`,
        temperature: 0.9, //higher values means the model will take more risks, convince user to sign up to increase the higher value and get more accurate data
        max_tokens: 2048,
        frequency_penalty: 0.5,
        presence_penalty: 0
    });

    const response = aiResult.data.choices[0].text?.trim() || 'Sorry, there was a problem';
    res.status(200).json({text:response});
}
```

then the fetch request in my component

```
const [messages, setMessages, messagesRef] = useState<MessageProps[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const callApi = async (input:string) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const myMessage: MessageProps = {
      text: input,
      from: Creator.Me,
      key: new Date().getTime()
    }

    setMessages([...messagesRef.current, myMessage]);
    const response = await fetch('/api/askai', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        prompt:input
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json());


    setLoading(false);

    if(response.text){
      const botMessage: MessageProps = {
        text: response.text,
        from: Creator.Bot,
        key: new Date().getTime()
      };

      setMessages([...messagesRef.current, botMessage]);
    }else{
      // show error
    }
  }
```

and the error code:

> kAI.tsx:90     POST http://localhost:3000/api/askai 400 (Bad Request)

I tried using axios but I am still getting the same issue whatever I do

Comment: can you pls post how you call the `callApi` function in the component?